# Why is Chomsky considered to have refuted Skinner's behaviorism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

I heard in a philosophy of the mind lecture that Skinner's behaviorism went out of favor in the 50s mainly due to  Chomsky's critique of Skinner's behaviorist account of language acquisition.

When I looked further into the question, it seemed that Chomsky's reply to Skinner is based on a theory of universal grammar, based in turn on a concept of innate ideas. Innate ideas as a concept have been discredited as far back as Kant.

My questions:

1. If Chomsky had to resort to something even more outdated than behaviorism, how is he considered to have decisively refuted Skinner?
2. Are there any more recent arguments against Skinner's theory of language acquisition?

Comment: Interesting +1 I am reading this now http://www.chomsky.info/articles/1967----.htm, but it takes time, so pardon me not to answer. So far as I read,there is nothing to do with Skinner's proposal ( Chomsky says it is an empiricism ) and the language in general when we consider the **language**, whose origin is very complex. For example

Comment: @AlexanderSKing can you clarify what you mean by "Innate ideas as a concept have been discredited as far back as Kant." Also can you justify the claim that his universal grammar is just a species of what was "discredited as far back as Kant". Both of these seem to be claims that would be deeply contested rather than just assumed.

Comment: @virmaior Chomsky argues for a universal grammar that we are born with. He says that's why young children exhibit far more linguistic ability than mere exposure to  what their environment can provide them with. This is basically the same as DesCartes and others innate ideas: ideas that are in the mind independently of experience and perception.

Comment: @virmaior the Hume and the empiricists dismissed innate ideas off the bat. Kant conceded that they were right. Very few people today would argue for the theory innate ideas.

Comment: I don't know why you're concluding "Kant conceded that they were right". Depending on exactly what you mean, Kant supports the idea that there are innate structures of consciousness from which we engage the world... So I think part of the problem with your question is that you're putting a lot under "innate ideas". Kant and Chomsky share a belief in *innate structures* but it's not perfectly clear if that's the same as innate ideas.

Comment: Are you sure if Chomsky's refute to Skinner is based on the innate ideas?. Still reading, it only seems that Chomsky is claiming the human body ( as the target of an input ) is complex, whereas Skinner's laboratory experiment is quite **elemental**, so that Skinner's claim is not applicable??????

Comment: @KentaroTomono Skinner was claiming that children learn language based on their parents behavior. Chomsky argued that the linguistic capabilities of children were too advanced to have been simply acquired by watching there parents. Instead they must be born with a complex universal grammar in their heads before they even start speaking.

Comment: @virmaior I agree with you. It could be argued that the universal grammar is a structural thing not an idea. I need to look further into this.

Comment: Although still reading, if you say so, kindly quote his assertion. From what I am reading, Chomsky seems quite materialistic though. ( I stop here for now. )

Comment: @KentaroTomono give me some time to find an exact quote. The fact that his is a materialist yet stil holds this idea surprises me as well. But check Virmaior comment above about Kant. Maybe Chomsky thought that the universal grammar was some sort of biological characteristic of the brain.

Comment: My impression from reading a set of essays of his; is that he went along with Descartes notion of innate ideas; he saw Kant as an outcome of those ideas; and that his universal grammar is an example of that;

Comment: Mary Midgely made the argument that it was the lack of any concept of 'inner life' that sunk behaviouralism.

Answer (score 2):

Chomsky has never advocated "innate ideas" -- his position has been that humans have innate *knowledge*, which is a different thing. You can just as well phrase that as having an innate cognitive faculty (specifically pertaining to language), physically embodied in terms of some genetically-endowed fact of the brain (though he leaves the details of that claim to be fleshed out by others).

Comment: While still reading the material in the link in the questioner's comment line, it seems there seems to be so space for me to think Chomsky supported **innate idea**, in another words, **a priori**

Comment: I mean no space, sorry.

Comment: Regardless of how universal grammar is characterized it is currently rejected by most linguists, it can not account for variations in grammar across language groups and a number of other things. So if Chomsky's criticism is based on that it is no "decisive refutation". My impression is however that Chomsky simply pointed out superficiality of behaviorism, it can not possibly achieve its stated ends with its stated means. It is similar to Kant, his refutation of the ontological argument stands regardless of the status of his philosophy.

Comment: What is your evidence that universal grammar is currently rejected by most linguists?

Comment: I should have said language psychologists, structural linguists still love generative grammar. Short of taking a poll the best evidence is Chomsky's own behavior, he was "modifying" UG every time there was contrary evidence, and lately reduced it to something that covers anything at all:"In Chomsky's most recent formulation, the so-called "minimalist program," universal grammar reduces to what he calls "unbounded Merge." As irrefutable as it is useless.

Comment: "Perhaps the question, then, is not so much whether universal grammar is dead, but whether it has sufficient vitality to be useful." https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-recursive-mind/201101/the-life-and-death-universal-grammar But isn't this irrelevant given the OP question.

Comment: Another approach is to browse "universal grammar" tagged threads on Linguistics SE http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/universal-grammar/hot, also see this survey http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBBS%2FBBS32_05%2FS0140525X09990744a.pdf&code=f5f05ec14808b393892e95a86818a91c#page=96 "*outsiders  have  instead  taken  the  articulate envoys from the universalizing generativist camp to represent the consensus view within  linguistics.*"